# Mount failed with "NFS: nfs4_discover_server_trunking unhandled error -22" - any suggestions?

Tags: mount, xubuntu, nfs

I have a Synology DS211J NAS attached to a Xubuntu box which I have been using as a backup server for several years and a number of version of Xubuntu without any issue.
I have just upgraded to 18.04LTS (from 16.04LTS) and this error has arisen the first time I try to mount the NAS. My standard command has been

```
 sudo mount IPaddress:/naspath /mountpath
```

and that has always worked.
Now when I issue the command I get a

```
 mount.nfs: mount system call failed
```

in the terminal window (I just issue the mount from a terminal as and when I need it), and in syslog:

```
 NFS: nfs4_discover_server_trunking unhandled error -22. Exiting with error EIO
```

I've searched for the error but cannot find anything recent and certainly nothing particularly informative. I did have a look and what the upgrade removed but, from memory, there was nothing suspicious. I suspect that there was some change that caused this problem but nothing obvious as far as I can see

Any suggestions ?

graham

Answer (score 1):

Irritatingly I have just found a solution, I did run the search again with the full error message and found

```
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=204532
```

and at the end the relevant advice to change the mount command to

```
mount -t nfs -o nolock,posix,nfsvers=3 ...
```

Obviously NFS has been updated and the Synology box hasn't (I might look at whether there are any updates for it)

I have tried the fix and it works here

I was debating whether to delete the question but as it applied to 18.04 it may be relevant to others and may be easier to find here.

Hope it is of use

graham

Comment: using nfsvers=3  fixed it for me too.